Is this the correct way to model a sample statistic: Bayesian vs Bootstrapping
I have 2 samples S1 & S2. Contain lead level margins, converted 1 or 0 flag. Need to compare metric sum(margin) /sum(converted) for both. Sample size is low for frequentist. I tried bootstrapping and doing pymc bayesian analysis but answer is way different... which is correct
with pm.Model() as model:
        # Weak Prior
        exp_rate= pm.Beta('exp_rate',a_p[i],b_p[i])
        # conversions
        n=pm.Binomial('enrollments', N[i],exp_rate,observed=num_enrollments[i])

        # Prior margin
        exp_mpu = pm.Normal('exp_mpu', m[i], s[i])
        std_mpu =pm.Uniform('std_mpu', lower=lower_mpu[i], upper=upper_mpu[i]) # pm.HalfNormal('std_mpu', sigma=s[i])

        # prior costs
        #exp_cost = pm.Normal('exp_cost', c[i], cs[i])
        #std_cost = pm.Uniform('std_cost', lower=lower_cost[i], upper=upper_cost[i])#pm.HalfNormal('std_cost', sigma=cs[i])#

        # Update with observed
        mpu_enr = pm.Normal('mpu_enr', mu=exp_mpu, sigma=std_mpu, observed=avg_mpu[i])
        #cost_of_failure = pm.Normal('cost_of_failure', mu=exp_cost, sigma=std_cost, observed=avg_cost[i])

        mpl_formula= pm.Deterministic('mpl_formula',n/N[i] * mpu_enr - (1-n/N[i]) *avg_cost[i])
        mpu_formula= pm.Deterministic('mpu_formula',mpu_enr - (N[i]/n-1) * avg_cost[i])

        # mpl_ratio = pm.Normal('mpl_ratio', mu=n/N[i] * mpu_enr - (1-n/N[i]) * cost_of_failure,sigma=standard_error_mpl[i])
        # mpu_ratio = pm.Normal('mpu_ratio', mu=mpu_enr - (N[i]/n-1) * cost_of_failure,sigma=standard_error_mpu[i])

        # Inference
        trace_group=  pm.sample(4000, tune=2000, target_accept=0.95, return_inferencedata=False)


prior_data_hybrid=prior_data[prior_data.experiment_event_variation=='Variation A']
prior_data_fulldig=prior_data[prior_data.experiment_event_variation=='Control']
observed_data_hybrid=observed_data[observed_data.experiment_event_variation=='Variation A']
observed_data_fulldig=observed_data[observed_data.experiment_event_variation=='Control']

prior_data_hybrid_enrolled=prior_data_hybrid[prior_data_hybrid.enrolled==1]
prior_data_fulldig_enrolled=prior_data_fulldig[prior_data_fulldig.enrolled==1]
observed_data_hybrid_enrolled=observed_data_hybrid[observed_data_hybrid.enrolled==1]
observed_data_fulldig_enrolled=observed_data_fulldig[observed_data_fulldig.enrolled==1]

use=0
# Data
n_leads = observed_data_hybrid.shape[0] + use*prior_data_hybrid.shape[0]
n_leads_full = observed_data_fulldig.shape[0] + use*prior_data_fulldig.shape[0]

n_successes = (observed_data_hybrid.shape[0] + use*prior_data_hybrid.shape[0])- (observed_data_hybrid['client_key'].isna().sum() + use*prior_data_hybrid['client_key'].isna().sum())
n_successes_full = (observed_data_fulldig.shape[0] + use*prior_data_fulldig.shape[0])- (observed_data_fulldig['client_key'].isna().sum() + use*prior_data_fulldig['client_key'].isna().sum())


n_failures = n_leads - n_successes
n_failures_full = n_leads_full - n_successes_full

# Beta distribution parameters
alpha_full = n_successes_full #+ 1
beta_full = n_failures_full #+ 1

alpha = n_successes #+ 1
beta = n_failures #+ 1

# Normal distribution parameters (based on observed data)

if use==1:
    debt =  np.concatenate((np.array(observed_data_hybrid_enrolled['estimated_total_debt__c']),np.array(prior_data_hybrid_enrolled['estimated_total_debt__c'])))
    debt_full =  np.concatenate((np.array(observed_data_fulldig_enrolled['estimated_total_debt__c']),np.array(prior_data_fulldig_enrolled['estimated_total_debt__c'])))
else:
    debt =  np.array(observed_data_hybrid_enrolled['estimated_total_debt__c'])
    debt_full =  np.array(observed_data_fulldig_enrolled['estimated_total_debt__c'])
    
mean_debt = np.mean(debt)
std_debt = np.std(debt)


mean_debt_full = np.mean(debt_full)
std_debt_full = np.std(debt_full)

# Bootstrap parameters
n_bootstrap_samples = 10000
debt_estimates = []
delta_debt=[]

# Generate bootstrap samples from the fitted Beta distribution
for _ in range(n_bootstrap_samples):
    # Sample a probability from the fitted Beta distribution
    p_sample = np.random.beta(alpha, beta)
    p_sample_full = np.random.beta(alpha_full, beta_full)

    # Generate a bootstrap sample using the sampled probability
    sampled_success = np.random.binomial(n_leads, p_sample)
    sampled_success_full = np.random.binomial(n_leads, p_sample_full)
    # Generate actual marketing margin from normal distribution
    sampled_debt = np.random.normal(mean_debt, std_debt,sampled_success)
    sampled_debt_full = np.random.normal(mean_debt_full, std_debt_full,sampled_success_full)
    
    sampled_debt=np.sum(sampled_margin)/sampled_success
    sampled_debt_full=np.sum(sampled_margin_full)/sampled_success_full
    d=sampled_debt-sampled_debt_full
    delta_debt.append(d)

```

